# Is there a way I can get a script / schema of my SQL Server Database with SSMS?

Tags: sql-server

I just lost some stored procedures in a test database. So I don't have to go through this again is there a way I can generate a script that I could use to recreate ALL my database objects.  I am using the SSMS so I am hoping there's some option with that which will allow me to get a script for recreation of everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Right Click (the database in object explorer)
- Tasks
- Generate Scripts

or use a version control tool or documentation tool from some one like redgate

finally you could simply take regular backups

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, you can generate scripts using management studio for any views or functions but

The ideal way is to keep a repository of every object in SVN , TFS or something similar.
We do it for our dev, test (and off course for prod). We do not treat non-prod environments as non-important.